# Sendgrid in Powershell : Adds a "?" before the variable in subject and body

Tags: powershell, sendgrid

I am trying to send emails using Sendgrid in Powershell.

```
$Parameters = @{
    ToAddress   = "blabla@centoso.com"
    FromAddress = "blabla@centoso.co"
    Subject    = "Your files for the job $file are ready for download"
    Body        =  $downloadurl
    APIKey      = "blabla"
 }

SendGridMail @Parameters
```

Looking at the variables in Powershell they are:

```
$file = test.zip
$downloadurl = "https://centoso.com/centoso-download/$file"
$downloadurl - Outputs "https://centoso.com/centoso-download/test.zip"
```

but when I receive the Sendgrid email :

```
$file = ?test.zip
$downloadurl = "https://centoso.com/centoso-download/?test.zip"
```

This is the SendGridMail function which I used on several occasions:

```
Function SendGridMail {
    param (
        [cmdletbinding()]
        [parameter()]
        [string]$ToAddress,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$FromAddress,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$Subject,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$Body,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$APIKey
 )
   
    $SendGridBody = @{
        "personalizations" = @(
            @{
                "to"= @(
                              @{
                                   "email" = $ToAddress
                               }
                 )
                "subject" = $Subject
            }
        )
                "content"= @(
                              @{
                                    "type" = "text/plain"
                                    "value" = $Body
                               }
                 )
                "from"  = @{
                            "email" = $FromAddress
                           }
              

}
$BodyJson = $SendGridBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
#Header for SendGrid API
$Header = @{
    "authorization" = "Bearer $APIKey"
}
#Send the email through SendGrid API
$Parameters = @{
    Method      = "POST"
    Uri         = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send"
    Headers     = $Header
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Body        = $BodyJson
}
Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters
```

}

I have used this function on different other scripts, but I do not understand where the question mark is coming from.

Comment: Where does the value stored in `$file` come from?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen $file = gci $download | select -Last 1
$file.Name | Out-file "C:\Hamillroad\Bellissima Web GUI\scripts\file.txt"

Comment: I think you need to share with us the `SendGridMail` function you're using for us to understand what's going on.

Comment: I tested your code with my API key and didn't see the `?` character. My guess is that the actual file name you're having issues for includes some hidden or non-ascii character and thats being converted to a ? when it goes through sendgrid. Use Notepad++ to look at file.txt and turn on "Show All Characters".

Comment: Along the same lines as @MarkWragg, try outputting of ```$file.Length``` and ```$downloadUrl.Length``` to make sure they match what you'd expect. If you've got a non-printing character in the filename it might get converted to a ```?``` if it's converted from Unicode to ASCII, and / or your source code might have a non-printing character in it that's getting munged into ```$downloadUrl``` somehow. Either way, if the length doesn't match your expectations it might help narrow down the search (or eliminate it as a possibility)...

Comment: Thanks, @mcIayton have followed your advice and I can see this: UpdateCredits-29-06-2022.zipCRLF and a new line. But for some reason, I can not remove them.